# Can I Import a Photo?

Tags: import

Ok, so can I import a photo from my computer onto a canvas? I have a picture that I want to kind of trace over for the outline of a character in an animation. Am I able to import it so that I can do so?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the add on "import image as plane"[image]

then you can add a plane image with shift + a:

[image]

then you will have to choose your image and it will import it as a plane, turn material below the 3D viewport to see your image:[image]

Another way is to use background image (press N to open the right panel on the 3D viewport) you will see your background image only with the orthographic view (hotkey 5) and front side or top view (depending what your choice on the background image panel):

[image]

Here the slider with the 0.1 and 2.4 value are for the lateral an vertical position.